# React hooks with async fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React hooks, but I'm trying to use a `useEffect` with a `useCallback`, but getting the notorious `React Hook "useList" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` error.

This file holds the `makeRequest`:

```
function useConnections = () => {
    const makeRequest = React.useCallback(async (props) => {
        // Determine base url, determine headers here
        const response = fetch(url, options);
        
        return response;
    }

    return { makeRequest };
}
```

This file is my `useListProvider`:

```
function useListProvider = () => {
    const { makeRequest } = useConnections();

    const useList = React.useCallback(async (props) => {
        // makerequest is just a wrapper for fetch with a bunch of needed headers.
        const response = await makeRequest(props);

        return { body: response.body };
    }

    return { useList };
}
```

This is the rendered page:

```
function MainPage() {
    const [isBusy, setIsBusy] = React.useStore(false);
    const { useList } = useListProvider();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!isBusy) { useList(); setIsBusy(false); } // ERROR HERE!
    }, [useList]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            IsBusy: {isBusy}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Maybe I'm not getting it, but I only want to grab the `useList` data when the state says it's not busy.  However, doing it this way, I get the error listed above. I understand I can't think of this the same way as Component classes, but how would you approach single and multiple renders from a callback?

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here because I'm doing something similar in the `useConnections`, etc. and not getting the same error?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The lint rule for hooks assumes that things which start with "use" are hooks. Thus it thinks that useList is a hook and trying to enforce the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) on it. But it's not actually a hook, it's just a normal function, so you just need to give it a different name and the lint rule will be satisfied.

```
function useListProvider = () => {
    const { makeRequest } = useConnections();

    const callback = React.useCallback(async (props) => {
        const response = await makeRequest(props);

        return { body: response.body };
    }, [makeRequest])

    return { callback };
}

// elsewhere:

const { callback } = useListProvider();

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isBusy) { 
      callback(); 
      setIsBusy(false);
    }
}, [callback]);
```

Why is it not a hook? Well, a hook is either one of the built in hooks, or a function that calls one of the built in hooks. Your callback doesn't meet those criteria. It was *created* by useCallback, but that just means it's a memoized function, not a hook.