# Use output from axios API in one function and pass to another

Tags: reactjs, axios

Team any better way to get data from Axios API and then use it in the same function as data.

```html
import React, { Component, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import { COLUMNS } from './columns';
import axios from 'axios';


export const BasicTable = () => {
      const [myresponse, setmyresponse] =useState([]);
      axios.get('http://localhost:5001/inventory/cluster/cluster1/servertype/test1')
      .then((response) => {
        const myresponse= response.data;
        setmyresponse(myresponse)
      });

      const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
      const data = useMemo(() => myresponse,[])
      const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns: columns,
        data: data
      })
      
    const { getTableProps,getTableBodyProps, headerGroups,rows,prepareRow } =tableInstance
    
    return(
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead >
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {
                headerGroup.headers.map(column =>(
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                ))}
            </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>

          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {
              rows.map(row => {
                prepareRow(row)
                return (
                  <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                    {
                      row.cells.map(cell =>{
                        return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                      })
                    }

                </tr>
                )
              })
            }

          </tbody>
      </table>
    )
};
```

What's happening right now, is I get data using console.log but the requests keep running indefinitely to my Axios API. Any thoughts on what am doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks with async fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244273/react-hooks-with-async-fetch)

Comment: Not sure how to fit this in my case, basically I want the output of api in myresponse variable which I can use further.

Comment: Please read [ask], [mcve] and "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
along with "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)". Images of text are unwanted. Copy the text and paste it into your question, [formatting it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this: I have used  `useEffect` so that your API gets called only once after your component did mount.

```
  useEffect(() => {
     axios
       .get('http://localhost:5001/inventory/cluster/cluster1/servertype/test1')   
       .then((response) => {
            const myresponse= response.data;
            setmyresponse(myresponse)
        });
   }, [])
    
   const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
   const data = useMemo(() => myresponse,[myresponse])
   const tableInstance = useTable({
      columns: columns,
      data: data
   });
```